# Fabric: Issue with post processing on iOS

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric

I've integrated Fabric into a Unity project but on iOS i have encounter a problem when building the project. At post processing, i get this error Exception: Invalid PBX project (parsing line 1902). If i go to the project and search for the 1902 line i get this:

```
shellPath = "/bin/sh -x";
chmod u+x ./Frameworks/Plugins/iOS/Fabric/Fabric.framework/uploadDSYM
./Frameworks/Plugins/iOS/Fabric/Fabric.framework/run 1514f154dd8b1c500035e106800ec5b702549f80 7a48022fc97d209fbd6daf0b9c84c7bc2570f29f7d9e4e73a804a1d6af222671 --skip-check-update";
        };
```

I've checked in the `FabricPostBuildiOS` script and i should have something like:

```
 shellPath = "/bin/sh -x";
 shellScript = .....
```

I don't know what is going wrong there but i need some help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `shellScript =` is being removed in the block of the pbxproject crashlytics is creating in its post build script.

If you change the build step to be the last one that happens (i.e. make it 1000) do you still get this error?

Comment: I tried setting the order to 1000, I don't get the error anymore but the reporting doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Are you seeing any missing dSYM messages on the dashboard after you cause a test crash?

Comment: I've uploaded the dSYM and i received a crash today, so all is good.

Comment: Great to hear it.